# Expressjs: google-auth-libary id-token verification "token used too late number > number..."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-oauth

I have tried to add google auth login for my reactjs/expressjs web app. On the frontend I am using the react-google-login package:

```
import React from "react"
import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login"
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

const axios = require('axios')

export default function LoginButton() {
    let history = useHistory()
    const { REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, REACT_APP_API_URL } = process.env

    const onSuccess = async (response) => {
        console.log(response)
        const data = { token: response.tokenId }
        const res = await axios.post(REACT_APP_API_URL + "/auth/google", data, {
            'Content-Type' : 'text/json'
        })
            .then((res) => {
                history.push('/home')
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("[LOGIN FAILED]")
            })
    }

    const onFailure = (response) => {
        console.log(response)
    }
    return(
        <GoogleLogin 
            clientId={REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
            buttonText="Log in with Google"
            onSuccess={onSuccess}
            onFailure={onFailure}
            cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
        />
    )
}
```

From what it seems I am getting the correct data from this button. I am sending the token to the expressjs api. This is where I am having issues. When using google-auth-library to verify the token I am getting the error: "Error: Token used too late, number_1 > number_2". As far as I know the idToken has expired, but isn't it weird considering I sent it as soon as possible from the frontend. Backend code:

```
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library')
require('dotenv').config()
const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.CLIENT_ID)


const postGoogleLogin = async (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.body
    try{
        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: token,
            audience: process.env.CLIENT_ID
        })
        
        const { name, email, picture } = ticket.getPayload()

        res.status(201).json({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            picture: picture
        })
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }   
}
```

I have tried to verify the token using the endpoint https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123 which says the token is valid, but as far as I know this endpoint should not be used in production

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be from the library itself. As long as you're using the same client id on both React and ExpressJs, verifyIdToken should return a success response as long as the token is still valid.

Also, you can make use of https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123 in your production code.

Internally, the library call the same endpoint to verify your token.